# Bloqueando datas do banco de dados no datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, datepicker

Criei um sistema para um condomínio e na área de reserva do salão de festas usei um datepicker, mas é aí que está; o síndico quer que as data já agendadas que estão no banco de dados "mysql" estejam bloqueadas no datepicker. O sistema foi feito em PHP.
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdebJ.jpg)
Eu preciso fazer uma consulta do banco de dados, buscar as datas já agendadas e no calendário do datepicker, essas datas estejam bloqueadas.

Comment: aqui deve te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score -2):

Para bloquear datas específicas no datepicker (seleção de data) a partir de um banco de dados, você pode seguir os seguintes passos:

Crie uma tabela no banco de dados para armazenar as datas bloqueadas. Essa tabela deve ter pelo menos os seguintes campos:

id: um identificador único para cada data bloqueada
data: a data que será bloqueada
Quando o usuário acessar a página com o datepicker, faça uma consulta ao banco de dados para obter as datas bloqueadas. Por exemplo, em PHP:

```
$datas_bloqueadas = array();

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT data FROM datas_bloqueadas");
while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
  $datas_bloqueadas[] = $linha['data'];
}
```

Inclua as datas bloqueadas no datepicker usando o atributo data-date-disabled e um array de strings com as datas no formato YYYY-MM-DD. Por exemplo:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" data-date-disabled='["<?php echo implode('","', $datas_bloqueadas); ?>"]'>
```

Isso fará com que o datepicker bloquee as datas que estão armazenadas no banco de dados.